# Estout and dcolumn: Overriding decimal alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I'm using estout (esttab actually) to produce a table in Latex from Stata. I'm using the dcolumn package to align the decimal places in my table.

I want to override the alignment for a single row; to be specific the number of observations row. Is there a way of doing this? Or, equivalents, if there a way to prefix each element in a row with "\multicolumn{1}{c}{" and suffix with "}", which would override the dcolumn alignment?

Example:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{My Table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule        
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean/s.d.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean/s.d.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean/s.d.}\\
\midrule
Var A               &        8.68&        8.51&        8.92\\
                    &        2.42&        2.51&        2.26\\
Var B               &        2.14&        1.98&        2.37\\
                    &        1.33&        1.29&        1.35\\
\midrule
Observations        &       38040&       22054&       15986\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Someone should move this to [tex.se], you'll get quicker and better answers there.

Answer (score 4):

The excellent [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package would make things a bit easier.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{My Table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S}}\toprule        
                   & {Mean/s.d.} & {Mean/s.d.} &{Mean/s.d.} \\ \midrule
      Var A        & 8.68        & 8.51        & 8.92       \\
                   & 2.42        & 2.51        & 2.26       \\ \addlinespace
      Var B        & 2.14        & 1.98        & 2.37       \\
                   & 1.33        & 1.29        & 1.35       \\ \midrule 
      Observations & {38040}     & {22054}     & {15986}    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The additional grouping with curly braces lets the concerned cell content appear as simple text and not as a number to be parsed. Details for customization in the package manual.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with the `layout` suboption of `stats`? It looks like it accepts the text entry, so you might want to try something like

```
estout ... , stats(N , layout("\multicolumn{1}{c}{@}"))
```

Hm. If I try it as

```
    sysuse auto, clear
    reg mpg wei for
    estout , stats(N , layout("\multicolumn{1}{c}{@}"))
```

it seems to produce the formatting in the variables column, as well. Ah well.

Comment: The stats(.) option does work, but requires a slight modification: stats(N,layout("\multicolumn{1}{c}{@} label("Observations")) - this overrides the multicolumn wrapper around the variable name. Thanks StasK!